# AOSP Source properties in the Database

Tags: android-source

Where can I find the databases from the AOSP Source? I mean the databases, in which are the properties, such as build informations, are stored. I Need this databases with a view to Change the properties before I compile the AOSP.

Comment: The build properties are generated during the build and stored in text files that end up in the device's file system. It is possible to set makefile variables to affect this, however. If you're more specific about what you want to do it'll be easier to give a good answer.

Comment: Other question at this point:

Where can I find this text files? Can I modify it?

It would be enough for me, when I can change the properties before I start the compiled android on a device or in a emulator.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A lot of them are done by setprop command line app during the init scripts processing.
Checkout the /init*.rc  in the device.

```
adb shell grep setprop /init*rc

adb shell cat /default.prop
```

They can also be easily added in C/C++ and Java code.

Comment: Thank you for the information.
Another question about this, are the init process the earliest moment to change/set the properties?